# Prevent the reading of video react native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-video

I am currently developing an application that enables the user to view sports videos and I would like to implement the following feature :
The user is presented with a list of videos but can only see the next ones if he first views the first ones. At the moment I have simply added a lock on the thumbnail of the videos that should be blocked but the user can still click a bit aside and play the video. I have look through all the props of the package react-native-video but didn't see any that would fit my need. At
Would you have ideas ? [image]

Here is also a sample of the code :

```html
<View style={styles.videoRow}>
            <View>
              <Video
                style={styles.image}
                source={{uri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/roundpower-88ef9.appspot.com/o/BootyAbsPower%2FTuto%2013.mp4?alt=media&token=da011245-fce2-4796-a78b-3abc518c73ef'}}
                useNativeControls
                resizeMode="contain"
                isLooping
                onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(playbackStatus) => onPlaybackStatusUpdate3(playbackStatus)}
              />
              {!debloque3 ? <View>
                <FontAwesome5 name="lock" size={40} color="white" style={styles.icon}/>
              </View> : <Text>''</Text>}

            </View>
            <View>
              <Video
                style={styles.image}
                source={{uri: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/roundpower-88ef9.appspot.com/o/BootyAbsPower%2FTuto%2014.mp4?alt=media&token=cd3d12be-05fd-4fc4-91d9-cd518faf14ce'}}
                useNativeControls
                resizeMode="contain"
                isLooping
                onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(playbackStatus) => onPlaybackStatusUpdate4(playbackStatus)}
              />
              {!debloque4 ? <View>
                <FontAwesome5 name="lock" size={40} color="white" style={styles.icon}/>
              </View> : <Text>''</Text>}
            </View>
          </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, a really easy way you can do this is just prevent the thing you don't want to the user to tap on from receiving any `pointerEvent`s (i.e. touch events).

A really simple quick-and-dirty way of doing this like so:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const onPress = () => console.error("I don't want this to happen.");

export default () => (
  <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.center]}>
    {/* red box in the middle */}
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={onPress}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      />
      {/* Obscure the TouchableOpacity with a View which completely covers it */}
      {shouldPreventTouches && <View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} />}
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Alternatively, you could also just wrap the `<Video />` component within a `<View />` and `useState` to toggle between `pointerEvents="none"` and `pointerEvents="auto"`. Both have the same effect of preventing touch information from being passed to children:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const onPress = () => console.error("I don't want this to happen.");

export default () => (
  <View style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, styles.center]}>
    {/* red box in the middle */}
    <View
      pointerEvents={shouldPreventTouches ? 'none' : 'auto'}
      style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={onPress}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
      />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

Depends what you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You could reuse the logic you have for showing the lock or not on the video element, and render the video only if it is unlocked.

```js
    <View>
    {
        debloque ? <Video/> : <FontAwesome5 name="lock" size={40} color="white" style={styles.icon} />
    }
    </View>
```

Alternatively you could set the source of the video to null until it is unlocked, to initialize the player but prevent anything to be played, according to [the docs](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#source).

Comment: Thanks a lot but the problem is that I want the user to see the thumbnail of the video. But what I can do is replace the video with just the video thumbnail if the video is locked ! Thanks a lot !